# Augmented Reality For Fitting Room Where to start?

Tags: android, image-processing, mobile, augmented-reality, virtual-reality

I have no experience in augmented reality nor image processing. And I know there are lots of document in the internet but to look for right places I should know basic stuff at first. I'm planning to code an android app which will use augmented reality for virtual fitting room. And I have determined some functionalities of app. My question is how could i manage to do those functionalities, which topics should i look into,  where to start, which key functionalities app should achieve and which open-source sdk you would suggest. So I can do deeper researches

-- Virtualizing clothes which will be provided by me and make them usable for app

-- Which attributes should virtualized clothes have and how to store them

-- Scan real-life clothes, virtualize them and make usable for app

-- Tracking human who will try on those clothes

-- Human body size can change so clothes which will fit on them should also resized for each person

-- Clothes should be looked as realistic as possible

-- Whenever a person moves, clothes should also move with that person (person bends, clothes also bends and fits on that person). And it should be quick as possible as it gets.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am in this situation now

Comment: Nope I haven't. So I let it go. What about you @monabaharlou ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried Snapchat's face filters?

It's essentially the same problem. They need to:

1. Create a model of a face (where are the eyes, nose, mouth, chin, etc)
2. Create a texture to map onto the model of the face
3. Extract faces from an image/video and map the 2D coordinates from the image to the model of the face you've defined
4. Draw/Render the texture on top of the image/video feed

Now you'd have to do the same, but instead you'd do it for a human body.

The issues that you'd have to deal with is the fact that only "half" of your body would be visible to your camera at any time (because the other half is facing away from the camera). Also your textures would have to map to a 3D model, vs a relatively 2D model of a face (facial features are mostly on a flat plane which is a good enough estimation).

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any idea which SDK would be more convenient ?

Comment: I'm not aware of any SDK that gives you this out of the box. You can try various computer vision APIs that might give you some of this information. I suspect that if you want this, then you'll have to build a large part of it yourself